# Intellij code style: Groovy continuation indents not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

Here is my Groovy tabs and indents configuration:

[image: Groovy]

However, the 2-space continuation indents do not work. My code looks like this, all in one line:

[image]

I would like the continuations to look like this (same code as formatted in Java):

[image]

My Java tabs and indents configuration is the same as Groovy above:

[image]

Why is the Groovy code formatting not working?